# Removing substrings from a string in Python?

Tags: python, string, numbers, web-crawler

I´m currently facing the problem that I have a string (deeplink) of which I want to extract one certain substring:

```
   <deeplink>https://www.jsox.de/tokyo-l200/tokio-skytree-ticket-fuer-einlass-ohne-anstehen-t107728/?partner_id=M1</deeplink>

   <deeplink>https://www.jsox.de/tokyo-l201/ganztaegige-bustour-zum-fuji-ab-tokio-t65554/?partner_id=M1</deeplink>
```

I expect to get extract the following information from the strings above:

```
t107728
t65554
```

How can I only extract for example the substring `t107728` from the the first string above? 
I tried it with the split and sub function but it does not work out

Can you guys help me out? Any feedback is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re`:

```
import re
s = ['<deeplink>https://www.jsox.de/tokyo-l200/tokio-skytree-ticket-fuer-einlass-ohne-anstehen-t107728/?partner_id=M1</deeplink>', '<deeplink>https://www.jsox.de/tokyo-l201/ganztaegige-bustour-zum-fuji-ab-tokio-t65554/?partner_id=M1</deeplink>']
new_s = [re.findall('[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?=/\?)', i)[0] for i in s]
```

Output:

```
['t107728', 't65554']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one, using the `split` function:

```
strings = ["<deeplink>https://www.jsox.de/tokyo-l200/tokio-skytree-ticket-fuer-einlass-ohne-anstehen-t107728/?partner_id=M1</deeplink>", "<deeplink>https://www.jsox.de/tokyo-l201/ganztaegige-bustour-zum-fuji-ab-tokio-t65554/?partner_id=M1</deeplink>"]

results = [elem.split("/?")[0].split("-")[-1] for elem in strings]

print(results)
```

Output:

```
['t107728', 't65554']
```